# My Salesforce password changed and now my Ruby on Rails app is broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, salesforce, oauth-2.0

I have a simple demo app set up to be able to access Salesforce.com from a Ruby on Rails app.  My code is extremely simple:

```
def sign_in_salesforce
  client = OAuth2::Client.new(ENV['SALESFORCE_CONSUMER_KEY'], ENV['SALESFORCE_CONSUMER_SECRET'], :site => 'https://login.salesforce.com/', :authorize_url => 'services/oauth2/authorize', :token_url => 'services/oauth2/token')
  auth_url = client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => 'https://99.44.242.76:3000/users/oauth_callback')
  redirect_to auth_url
end
```

I then have a method to take care of the callback.

```
  def oauth_callback
    db_client = Databasedotcom::Client.new
    db_client.authenticate(:token => params[:code])
    puts db_client.inspect
  end
```

The error in the console is: 
    ArgumentError (ArgumentError):
      app/controllers/users_controller.rb:60:in `oauth_callback'

The line that is causing the error is:

```
db_client.authenticate(:token => params[:code])
```

like the token that I am getting is invalid or something.

It worked fine until I changed my Salesforce password (which they required me to do).  What am I missing?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: how is it not working?

Comment: Sorry, sometimes I am an idiot.  The question should be more clear now.

Comment: what's in the params dictionary ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response you receive is that your refresh token is no longer valid then you need to restart the OAuth process from scratch to obtain a new refresh token; you can then use to get new session tokens in subsequent uses of the app as you have been up until now.

Essentially, start the process as you would for the very first time the app is launched.

Comment: I believe that is what I am doing.  I am starting the server, hitting the link in my app, being redirected to Salesforce, and then it is throwing the error.  Am I missing a step?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it... Have you checked the app config in salesforce to see if any changes were made there? I think you're going to have to paste some code or a link to your app

Comment: You were right.  Changes had been made to the app in my Saleforce config.  I made sure I had the right KEY and SECRET and everything worked according to plan.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: No worries - another point to note is that the settings for OAuth in Salesforce are cached... if you change them in the org it can take a few minutes before they take effect; not allowing for that can cause a lot of torment!

Comment: lol.  I wish I would of know that this morning.  I thought I was going  to have to remove your check mark.  Thanks for the info.